# SQL request never ends

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to get some data from my Cassandra database using in a program, but the request never completes.

My Spark configuration looks like this:

```
object ExternalConf {
    var cassandraHost : String = "cassandra_cassandra-001,cassandra_cassandra-002,cassandra_cassandra-003,cassandra_cassandra-004"
    var masterSpark: String ="local[*]"
}

object Spark {
  val session : SparkSession = SparkSession
              .builder()
              .appName("KStreaming")
              // .config("spark.cassandra.connection.host", ExternalConf.cassandraHost) //default value or args
              .config("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "cassandra_node") //preprod
              .config("spark.cassandra.auth.username", "cassandra")
              .config("spark.cassandra.auth.password", "cassandra")
              .config("output.batch.grouping.buffer.size", "50")
              .config("output.batch.size.bytes", "102400")
                            .config("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "4g")
                            .config("spark.sql.broadcastTimeout",  "1800")
              .master(ExternalConf.masterSpark)
              .getOrCreate();

    session.sql("CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW dbv2_product_categories USING org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra OPTIONS (table 'dbv2_product_categories', keyspace 'preprod', pushdown 'true')")
    import session.implicits._
}
```

And the code that makes a SELECT:

```
    def extractData(data: RDD[ConsumerRecord[String, String]]) = {
        import Spark.session.implicits._
        data
            .foreach(message => {
                var persistedProductCategory: DataFrame = Spark.session.sql("SELECT * FROM dbv2_product_categories WHERE account_id = '" + accountId + "' AND name = '" + shopifyProduct.product_type + "'")
            })
    }
```

The request never ends. Here is my stderr (I stripped the beginning of it to make it shorter):

```
22/08/29 09:50:04 INFO ConsumerConfig: ConsumerConfig values: 
    metric.reporters = []
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    partition.assignment.strategy = [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
    bootstrap.servers = [kafka:9092]
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    enable.auto.commit = false
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    interceptor.classes = null
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    client.id = consumer-4
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
    max.poll.records = 2147483647
    check.crcs = true
    request.timeout.ms = 40000
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    group.id = spark-executor--183698333
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.key.password = null
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    session.timeout.ms = 30000
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    auto.offset.reset = none

22/08/29 09:50:04 WARN ConsumerConfig: The configuration schema.registry.url = http://schema-registry:8081 was supplied but isn't a known config.
22/08/29 09:50:04 INFO AppInfoParser: Kafka version : 0.10.0.1
22/08/29 09:50:04 INFO AppInfoParser: Kafka commitId : a7a17cdec9eaa6c5
22/08/29 09:50:04 INFO CachedKafkaConsumer: Initial fetch for spark-executor--183698333 62c44e48be54d0002900bd62_products 0 0
22/08/29 09:50:04 INFO AbstractCoordinator: Discovered coordinator kafka:9092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null) for group spark-executor--183698333.
22/08/29 09:50:04 WARN SparkContext: Using an existing SparkContext; some configuration may not take effect.
22/08/29 09:50:04 INFO SharedState: Setting hive.metastore.warehouse.dir ('null') to the value of spark.sql.warehouse.dir ('file:/opt/spark/work/driver-20220829094956-7907/spark-warehouse').
22/08/29 09:50:04 INFO SharedState: Warehouse path is 'file:/opt/spark/work/driver-20220829094956-7907/spark-warehouse'.
22/08/29 09:50:05 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1661766605000 ms
22/08/29 09:50:05 INFO StateStoreCoordinatorRef: Registered StateStoreCoordinator endpoint
22/08/29 09:50:05 INFO SparkSqlParser: Parsing command: CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW dbv2_product_categories USING org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra OPTIONS (table 'dbv2_product_categories', keyspace 'kiliba', pushdown 'true')
22/08/29 09:50:07 INFO ClockFactory: Using native clock to generate timestamps.
22/08/29 09:50:07 INFO NettyUtil: Found Netty's native epoll transport in the classpath, using it
22/08/29 09:50:07 INFO Cluster: New Cassandra host cassandra_node/10.0.0.177:9042 added
22/08/29 09:50:07 INFO CassandraConnector: Connected to Cassandra cluster: Test Cluster
22/08/29 09:50:08 INFO SparkSqlParser: Parsing command: SELECT * FROM dbv2_product_categories WHERE account_id = 'shopifytest_62c44e48be54d0002900bd62' AND name = ''
22/08/29 09:50:08 INFO CassandraSourceRelation: Input Predicates: [IsNotNull(account_id), IsNotNull(name), EqualTo(account_id,shopifytest_62c44e48be54d0002900bd62), EqualTo(name,)]
22/08/29 09:50:08 INFO CassandraSourceRelation: Input Predicates: [IsNotNull(account_id), IsNotNull(name), EqualTo(account_id,shopifytest_62c44e48be54d0002900bd62), EqualTo(name,)]
22/08/29 09:50:08 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 175.144922 ms
22/08/29 09:50:08 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 16.62666 ms
22/08/29 09:50:08 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: count at Kstreaming.scala:361
22/08/29 09:50:08 INFO DAGScheduler: Registering RDD 7 (count at Kstreaming.scala:361)
22/08/29 09:50:08 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 1 (count at Kstreaming.scala:361) with 1 output partitions
22/08/29 09:50:08 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 2 (count at Kstreaming.scala:361)
22/08/29 09:50:08 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List(ShuffleMapStage 1)
22/08/29 09:50:08 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List(ShuffleMapStage 1)
22/08/29 09:50:09 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ShuffleMapStage 1 (MapPartitionsRDD[7] at count at Kstreaming.scala:361), which has no missing parents
22/08/29 09:50:09 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1 stored as values in memory (estimated size 15.8 KB, free 5.2 GB)
22/08/29 09:50:09 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 7.8 KB, free 5.2 GB)
22/08/29 09:50:09 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on 10.0.0.229:43123 (size: 7.8 KB, free: 5.2 GB)
22/08/29 09:50:09 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 1 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1006
22/08/29 09:50:09 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ShuffleMapStage 1 (MapPartitionsRDD[7] at count at Kstreaming.scala:361) (first 15 tasks are for partitions Vector(0))
22/08/29 09:50:09 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 1.0 with 1 tasks
22/08/29 09:50:10 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1661766610000 ms
22/08/29 09:50:15 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1661766615000 ms
22/08/29 09:50:16 INFO CassandraConnector: Disconnected from Cassandra cluster: Test Cluster
22/08/29 09:50:20 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1661766620000 ms
22/08/29 09:50:25 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1661766625000 ms
22/08/29 09:50:30 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1661766630000 ms
22/08/29 09:50:35 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1661766635000 ms
22/08/29 09:50:40 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1661766640000 ms
22/08/29 09:50:45 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1661766645000 ms
22/08/29 09:50:50 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1661766650000 ms
22/08/29 09:50:55 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1661766655000 ms
22/08/29 09:51:00 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1661766660000 ms
22/08/29 09:51:05 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1661766665000 ms
22/08/29 09:51:10 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1661766670000 ms
22/08/29 09:51:15 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1661766675000 ms
22/08/29 09:51:20 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1661766680000 ms
22/08/29 09:51:25 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1661766685000 ms
22/08/29 09:51:30 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1661766690000 ms
```

When I execute the SQL command directly in cqlsh, it works and I get a result almost instantly:

```
cqlsh:kiliba> SELECT * FROM dbv2_product_categories WHERE account_id = 'shopifytest_62c44e48be54d0002900bd62' AND name = '';

 account_id | name | id | breadcrumb | parent_id
------------+------+----+------------+-----------

(0 rows)
```

How comes my program fails to give me a response and seems to hang eternally?

Comment: You are trying to use the select statement inside the RDD foreach function which runs at the executors and not the driver. I think by the way your code is structured you are actually creating a new spark session on every executor (I might be wrong on that, you can check the stderr of any executor and you will see if a new session is created there)

Comment: One option would be to collect the data back to the driver (if its not big) and then execute your query for each record. simply add .collect() before call to foreach like this: data.collect().foreach(...). Other option is to convert the RDD to DataFrame and join it with the dbv2_product_categories table (which is much better in terms of performance and the Spark programming model)